# Package published to npm not running properly

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install

I  published a simple package to npm and it's not working properly when installed. The package.json is as follows

```
   {
     "name": "test-package-hello",
     "version": "1.0.4",
     "description": "This is a test package",
     "main": "index.js",
     "bin": {
       "hello": "index.js"
     },
     "scripts": {
      "test": "exit 0"
    },
    "author": "Jeril Sebastian",
    "license": "MIT",
    "dependencies": {
      "chalk": "^2.1.0"
    }
  }
```

I published the package using `npm publish` and it gets published successfully. Then I install it using `npm install -g test-package-hello` and it gets installed successfully.

But when I try to run the program using `hello`, it gives the error

```
/home/jeril/.nvm/versions/node/v6.11.3/bin/hello: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token `('
```

Apparently it's trying to run index.js as a bash script. When I examined other files in `/home/jeril/.nvm/versions/node/v6.11.3/bin/`, all of them have the this line on top

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
```

Where as my package's `index.js` doesn't have it on top.

What am i missing?
Find the source [here](https://github.com/jerilseb/test-package-hello) and the published package [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/test-package-hello)

Comment: So why don't you put the shebang line (“#!/usr/bin/env node”) at the beginning of your index.js file? It is necessary if you want to run it directly from the command line

Comment: @PatrickHund I have looked at the source of few packages and none of them add the line manually. It's supposed to be automatically inserted while installing the package. Also none of the online tutorials mention adding that line either.